# How do I detect if someone was typing but didn't send a message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm writing a Discord bot and I'm currently very stumped on how I could make a typing detection system in my bot. I want it to be able to detect when someone "Ghost types", or when they start typing and then delete their message, thereby stopping the typing indicator but never sending a message.

I know that there's an isTypingIn() function built into discord.js, but I want to make it so it can detect when anyone Ghost types at any time. Sadly, I don't have any code written for this right now but if anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There is an event specifically for when a user begins typing:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_typing

guild_subscriptions will need to be set to true for this to work.

The same events are available in discord.js:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-typingStart

Comment: That event is for discordpy, in python. My bot is written using the discord,js library in javascript.

Comment: The same event is available in discord.js. See my latest edit.

Comment: How can I set that guild_subscriptions event to true in discord.py, because I can't find any solution on documentation.